# Compiler error : The program '[10216] ConsoleApplication1.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b)

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

I'm trying the OpenCV library for my thesis. I already applied the steps given by http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2013/05/installing-configuring-opencv-with-vs.html My problem is that after building successfully I really think that the code should run properly. Please tell me the problem. Thanks :)

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
     Mat img(500, 1000, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0, 100)); //create an image ( 3 channels, 8 bit image depth, 500 high, 1000 wide, (0, 0, 100) assigned for Blue, Green and Red plane respectively. )

     if (img.empty()) //check whether the image is loaded or not
     {
          cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
          //system("pause"); //wait for a key press
          return -1; 
     } 

     namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window with the name "MyWindow"
     imshow("MyWindow", img); //display the image which is stored in the 'img' in the "MyWindow" window

     waitKey(0);  //wait infinite time for a keypress

     destroyWindow("MyWindow"); //destroy the window with the name, "MyWindow"

     return 0;
}
```

Build:
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  ConsoleApplication1.cpp
1>  ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj -> D:\Visual Studio\Projects\Project2\new\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Debug:
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\Visual Studio\Projects\Project2\new\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The program '[4136] ConsoleApplication1.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).

Comment: The linked article strongly encourages you to get this right by talking about how to setup the x86 version of the OpenCV.  Looks like you got this wrong anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[`NTSTATUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx) code of `0xC000007B` is `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`. Most likely your program is 32 bit and is trying to load 64 DLLs. Given that you mention OpenCV, I suspect that it's the OpenCV DLLs that are at the root of this.

Solutions:

1. Make sure that your process finds 32 bit versions of the DLLs.
2. Switch your project to target 64 bit.